# LaTex macro not properly executed in tabular environment

Tags: tables, macros, environments, grouping

I want to use a **macro** to set the separators (`&`,`\\`) **in a tabular environment**. The macro should thereby act as a Boolean switch with three states. Unfortunately I keep getting a result like this:

[image] instead of this: [image]

I have already tried the macro outside of the tabular environment where it's working fine. I believe the problem occurs because of some expansion issue but I don't know how to fix it. I have also tried to use a `\DeclareRobustCommand` or `\protect`, but the result is not affected.

Here is the code i used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Define command for automatic setting of delimeters
% Usage: \setdelim{<delim1>}{<delim2>}
\newbool{startflag}
\newbool{delimflag}
\newcommand*{\setdelim}[2]{%
    \ifbool{startflag}{
        \ifbool{delimflag}{% if true
        #1
        \boolfalse{delimflag}\ignorespaces
        }{}% false is somehow not working in tabular environment}
        \notbool{delimflag}{% if false
        #2
        \booltrue{delimflag}\ignorespaces
        }{}% true is as well not working in tabular environment}
    }{%
    \setbool{startflag}{true}
    \setbool{delimflag}{true}\ignorespaces
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{\span}{\cr} b
\setdelim{\span}{\cr} c
\setdelim{\span}{\cr} d

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
For those of you who are still wondering what's the reason for this whole cargo cult programming. I use `\setdelim` in the following command (modified command of posquit0's awesome-cv) to separate some optional information for the cv header.

```
\newcommand*{\@headersocial}[3][unframed]{%
        \global\boolfalse{startflag}% reset startflag
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{MapMarker}{\@address}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{Mobile}{\@mobile}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \href{mailto:\@email}{\icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{Envelope}{\@email}}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \href{http://\@homepage}{\icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{Home}{\@homepage}}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \href{https://github.com/\@github}{\icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{GithubSquare}{\@github}}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{Linkedin}{\@linkedin}}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \icon[##1]{\acvHeaderIconSize}{Skype}{\@skype}%
        }%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}%
            {}{%
            \@setdelim{##2}{##3}%
            \@extrainfo%
        }%
    }
```

This command allows me to print a header in a tabular environment, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Or like this using regular delimiters:

[image]

Comment: Out of cusriosity: Could you add some backgrond information on the use cases for such a  macro?

Comment: apart from the global issue mentioned in Skillmon's answer why are you inserting `\span` and `\cr` into a latex tabular, these are the underlying primitives and may possibly do something useful in some cases but they are not intended to be used in latex documents.

Comment: @leandriis I am currently setting up a CV-template where a table (for the social icons) is automatically generated with some optional variables as input. In order to achieve this I need a macro to decide whether to use the `&` separator or the `\\` separator.

Comment: @David Carlisle That's a rather good question, because I just realised that `&` and `\\` are working as well. Last time I tried to use them it didn't work. From now on I will use the tabular seperators.

Comment: `\cr` works a little bit like `\\ ` but `\span` does not work at all like `&` there is no alignment in that case , change `a` to `aaa` in  the answer below and you will see the | do not line up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no need to change anything, the misalignment already shows with `c` vs `a` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your boolean states won't be saved across columns and rows as each cell forms a group. Prefixing the `\booltrue` and `\boolfalse` calls with `\global` should solve this issue. Keep in mind that you'll have to reset the booleans to false for a new array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Define command for automatic setting of delimeters
% Usage: \setdelim{<delim1>}{<delim2>}
\newbool{startflag}
\newbool{delimflag}
\newcommand*{\setdelim}[2]
  {%
    \ifbool{startflag}
      {%
        \ifbool{delimflag}
          {%
            #1%
            \global\boolfalse{delimflag}%
          }
          {%
            #2%
            \global\booltrue{delimflag}%
          }%
      }
      {%
        \global\booltrue{startflag}%
        \global\booltrue{delimflag}%
      }%
    \ignorespaces
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}

\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{&}{\\} b
\setdelim{&}{\\} c
\setdelim{&}{\\} d

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

With the idea of [@UlrichDiez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570104/117050) to use the arguments `{init}{init}` as another flag, we can also make things work without global assignments. In the following each new cell has to be started with `\setdelim`. Since the boolean is always set after the next cell started (after `#1` and `#2`) the state carries over to the next cell.

I used `expl3` syntax for this example, just to have easy access to `\str_if_eq:nnTF` (a function comparing the two arguments as strings). This way I don't need the rather complicated test for both arguments being `init` provided by @UlrichDiez. Other solutions to get this test without `expl3` are of course possible. Note that between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` spaces are ignored, so I don't have to comment each line ending.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__erdinale_setdelim_bool
\cs_new_protected:Npn \erdinale_setdelim:nn #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { {#1} {#2} } { {init} {init} }
      { \bool_set_true:N \l__erdinale_setdelim_bool }
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l__erdinale_setdelim_bool
          {
            #1
            \bool_set_false:N \l__erdinale_setdelim_bool
          }
          {
            #2
            \bool_set_true:N \l__erdinale_setdelim_bool
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \setdelim \erdinale_setdelim:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{&}{\\} b
\setdelim{&}{\\} c
\setdelim{&}{\\} d
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{&}{\\} b
\setdelim{&}{\\} c
\setdelim{&}{\\} d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains quite a lot! Now it is working as it should, excpect for the `\ignorespaces`, I still have to put this command behind every boolean operation.

Comment: @Erdinale no, you don't have to. Just make sure to use `%` to comment out the space resulting from the new line after the closing and opening braces (there are some where it isn't necessary as there will be another argument grabbed, just like in my answer, after the first two arguments of `\ifbool` a `%` isn't necessary, but make sure to use it after the opening braces and the other closing braces!)

Comment: If someone had explained this to me earlier, he could have saved me a lot of trouble, haha. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Erdinale not clear why you are using `tabular` here since there is no alignment between the entries (as `\span` removes the alignment point)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but if he uses `&` and `\\ ` (like already explained in your comment and now shown in my answer) the `tabular` makes sense. I guess he was using `\span` because he had issues with TeX's parsing regarding `&` in `\valign` with some old or other code of his.

Comment: @ Skillmon You are absolutely right, this is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to start every tabular-environment's body  with `\setdelim{init}{init}`, then you can crank out the case of the concatenation of `\setdelim`'s first and second argument yielding the sequence `initinit` and do with only one flag.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CheckWhetherinitinit[1]{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletoexclam#1!}$%
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
     % As #1 can contain & and \\ \@firstofone{...} is needed to "hide" #1 from the tabular/alignment.
  {\expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{\forkinitinit#1!{\@firstoftwo}initinit!{\@secondoftwo}!!!}}%
  {\@secondoftwo}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\forkinitinit{\long\def\forkinitinit#1initinit!#2#3!!!{#2}}%
\@ifdefinable\gobbletoexclam{\long\def\gobbletoexclam#1!{}}%
\makeatother


% Define command for automatic setting of delimeters
% Usage: \setdelim{<delim1>}{<delim2>}
\newbool{delimflag}
\newcommand*{\setdelim}[2]{%
  \CheckWhetherinitinit{#1#2}{%
    \booltrue{delimflag}%
  }{%
    \ifbool{delimflag}{%
      #1%
      \boolfalse{delimflag}%
    }{%
      #2%
      \booltrue{delimflag}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{&}{\\} b
\setdelim{&}{\\} c
\setdelim{&}{\\} d
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{&}{\\} b
\setdelim{&}{\\} c
\setdelim{&}{\\} d
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(To be honest, I don't know what the benefit of

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\setdelim{init}{init} a
\setdelim{&}{\\} b
\setdelim{&}{\\} c
\setdelim{&}{\\} d
\end{tabular}
```

versus the considerably shorter

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}
```

is.)

Comment: The `initinit` solution is indeed preferable, as he has to set the flags to `false` to start a new `tabular` otherwise. But your `initinit` implementation seems a bit over the top, don't you think?

Comment: @Skillmon Maybe it seems a bit over the top, but I didn't see any other reliable way of implementing it expandably, i.e., without the need of having TeX define temporary macros whenever the check is carried out. As each temporary assignment costs memory it all also depends on how often the check is carried out during the LaTeX-run... The need of setting the flag to false at the beginning of each tabular is just hidden by the fact that the `initinit`-check does this. ;-)

Comment: `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\detokenize{{#1}{#2}}}{\detokenize{{init}{init}}}=0 ` <- expandably and robust, engine independent when using `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` and `\pdf@strcmp`.

Comment: The `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp` is essentially what `\str_if_eq:nnTF` does. Of course the big difference is that because of the `\detokenize` my approach loses category codes, but that doesn't seem important for this use.

Comment: @Skillmon With my implementation I actually test for an argument containing `!` as otherwise passing `<Whatsoever>initinit!<Whatsoever>` might outmanoeuvre the test with the argument delimited by `initinit!`.

Comment: Oh, you're right (missed that aspect). When I took a quick look it looked like the standard `\ifblank` test :)

Comment: @Skillmon I think our both tests are not completely engine-independent as we both use `\detokenize` which is an e-TeX-thing.  In order to work around that, one could do semething like `\newcommand\CheckWhetherNull[1]{\romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}{\@firstoftwo\expandafter{}\@firstoftwo}}%
`

Comment: Yes, but since the LaTeX kernel requires e-TeX nowadays, and e-TeX is around for a few years now (understatement...) with engine independent I usually mean works in pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX (and maybe even pTeX and upTeX). It makes, imho, not much sense to support non-e-TeX engines with contemporary LaTeX code. (it's hard enough not strictly requiring `\expanded`, yet)

Comment: @Skillmon When I read something like this and look at the Sanco 8001, which catches the dust on my desk, but still runs when I turn it on, I sometimes feel -eh- antiquated . ;-)